# From a phpunit script: Is it possible to exe a javascript file to enter a date in a datepicker that has a readonly input

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, selenium-chromedriver

I have a html file below, that I want to enter a date (eg. 25-07-1979).  The input is readonly.  I am wondering if I can include some javascript in the phpunit file that will make the field writable so I can enter a date.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" readonly="readonly"></p>
</body>
</html>
```